# how can i do this with js?

Tags: javascript, function

Hello this is my problem. I should make this code `[1,4,6,3,4,6].repeat()` return me as output this `[1,4,6,3,4,6,1,4,6,3,4,6]`. I didn't understand how to set the resolution though. Can you help me ?

Comment: Seems to me it's a simple concat with the same array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What do you mean you don't understand how to set the resolution? What do you even mean by resolution? Elaborate please.

Comment: What does *"I didn't understand how to set the resolution though."* mean?

Comment: Depeneding on what your question is really about, this might answer it if you need to repeat N times: [Repeat an array with multiple elements multiple times in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/50672126)

Comment: It's a shame the people answering don't take their time to understand the difficulty the user is having

Comment: @Greggz As far as I understand, OP is having difficulties getting their `repeat` method to resolve when called on an array object. No?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen He wasn't clear on the question. Before trying to resolve for him, guide him. About `prototypes`, about `Arrays` etc.. What you did was most probably solving his homework without any real effort from his part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
Array.prototype.repeat = function() {
  return [...this, ...this];
}

console.log([1,4,6,3,4,6].repeat())
```

Note that changing the prototype of built-in types is generally not a good idea, and can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: As far as I know, accessing an objects prototype and changing it is frowned upon. Am I right? Clarification: I asked this out of curiosity and to learn. The question is not sarcasm :)

Comment: @DogaOruc You are absolutely right, but such are the requirements of the question. I've added a note to the answer.

Comment: Almost every powerfull technique is frowned upon

Answer (score 3):

Use `.concat` on same array:

```js
var myArray = [1,4,6,3,4,6];
var newArray = myArray.concat(myArray);
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably can help you with your problem.
It let you define your own function for array.

```js
Array.prototype.repeat= function(){
  return this.concat(this);
}

[1,4,6,3,4,6].repeat();
```